LLM Based Chatbot for assessing students essays
I am developing an LLM-based chatbot for evaluating essays. Users will submit an essay, and the chatbot will identify errors, assess language clarity, and correct grammar, among other functions. I aim to provide the model with essays previously evaluated by teachers as reference points. However, I am not sure about the best approach to building this feature. Could you please advise on the most effective way to implement this functionality?
